# Is it possible to represent a closed substack as a fundamental cycle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be an Artin stack and $Z \subset X$ be a closed substack. Can we represent $Z$ as a fundamental cycle? i.e. $[Z] = \sum_i a_i [Z_i]$ where $Z_i$ are integral substacks of $X$. In other word, can we correspond an element $Z_*(X)$ correspond to the substack $Z \subset X$?

Considering some references, for example Edidin's 'Equivariant Intersection theory', I think that the answer of the above question may be negative. But I'm not very sure.